# Read asp.net textbox text using variable for name in VB.Net code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Situation:

I have an aspx content page that has an asp table. In the table there are 20 rows with only one column. Each cell has an asp textbox in it.

I have some code, vb.net, that adds text to the text box when a user clicks the button. This all works fine.

Now what I need to do, and can't seem to find anything that fits my situation exactly, is when a second button is clicked I need to "loop" through the textboxes.

I have a hidden label that has a count of how many text boxes are actually used so I can set the for/next loop. What i cannot seem to figure out is how exactly to get the contents of the textbox assigned to the vb variable.

I currently have this code:

```
for x As integer = 1 to fCount
    tName = "TextBox" & x
    Dim cFileName as String = CType(Controls(tName), TextBox).ToString()
    blah blah blah other code
Next
```

It errors out on the line that trys to assign the textbox text with the variable name tName. This is just the latest code I have tried. I have tried many others but I just can't seem to get it right.

My text boxes are named TextBox1, TextBox2, etc. all the way to TextBox20. The hidden file counter allows me to only try and retrieve the ones that have been used.

Any help would be greatly thanked!!

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Object can not be set to instance of object. It thinks the text box is blank but I know it is not.

Comment: You would get that error if `tName` was not an existing control name.

Comment: Which I understand and the root of my problem. How exactly do I use a variable to call a textbox??

Comment: The variable isn't the issue.  The value of the variable is the issue.  Verify `tName` contains a value corresponding to a control on your page.

Comment: I understand that the variable tName needs a value but i do NOT know how to get the asp.net textbox text value into the variable tName using a For Next loop that can increment the x value and append it to the textbox name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I tried on my computer.  It is structured a little differently to hopefully correct other errors you may encounter.  More importantly, the code works:

```
  For x As Integer = 1 To 20
     Dim tName As String = "TextBox" & x

     If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CType(Controls(tName), TextBox).Text) Then
        Dim cFileName As String = CType(Controls(tName), TextBox).Text
     End If
  Next
```

I got rid of `fCount` based on the assumption that if only `TextBox5` and `TextBox10` contained data, then `fCount` would be 2.  If this is true, then your loop would not be correct because you would be trying to grab `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`.

I changed `.ToString` to `.Text` to give you the contents of the control.

Going back to the error message, `Controls(tName)` must evaluate to a control on the page or you will get an error.

Comment: When I put this code in I get the following error: Input string was not in a correct format. This seems odd as the variable sFileName is defined as a string and the asp textbox control only has text in it. Also the fCount is used to only loop through as many times as there are textbox es used. They are assigned starting at 1 and increase sequentially. So why would it throw this error?